# How to Retrieve Lates SVN Revision Without SVN Access

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We have an SVN source tree checked out on Windows using a fairly recent version of SVN. We mount this tree through a shared folder on a Linux VM, where we do our builds. Unfortunately, the version of SVN on Linux is older than the one on Windows, so standard SVN commands universally fail.

This isn't too bad, but we'd really like to be able to retrieve the SVN revision number of the checkout, similar to what the svnversion command returns. That is, we want the most recent revision number in the entire tree.

Can this information be dredged directly out of the various files in .svn? We're using SVN r1.6.11, and this is unlikely to change, so we're not necessarily interested in a version-spanning solution  - just one specific to this release.

---

Sorry, that's not quite right. SVN 1.6.11 is the version we're using on Linux. The version used on Windows for the checkout that we want to peruse is 1.9.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere in SVN development the workingcopy format changed from file-based to database-based. Inside your working copy you will find a normal SQLlite database  in  .svn/wc.db.

The SQL command

`SELECT min(revision), max(revision) FROM NODES`

Retrieves the min revision and the maximum revision of all your files. You can find a large number of ways to connect to sqllite via perl, python or ruby.

Needless to say that this is in no way supported but you need a quick and dirty solution :)